# org.bson.types.ObjectId can not be found

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm getting this error for my java app:

```
org.bson.types.ObjectId can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly.
```

I have `mongo-2.7.2.jar` in the Java Build path

And BTW, it's weird because I can fairly use other Class and Methods in the mongo library jar.

Comment: That class is in the mentioned .jar so your issue is not related to mongodb but your understanding (or lack thereof) of getting library JARs in your classpath. Please retag as Java (and possibly your IDE)

Comment: Ok I tagged it with Java. I really find this problem weird since I can use other class and functions in the same library.

Comment: Try opening the jar and see if it's in there

Comment: yes it's there. I totally overlooked my code, I was defining the ObjectId in the "shared" code of GWT, I totally forgot that I am placing it on a Java code that will be compiled into javascript. I guess this question needs to be closed.